# Number format in thousands on highcharts in wpdatatable plugin

Tags: plugins, php, javascript

The plugin wpdatatables converts the last zeros with "k" in highcharts and i cant figure out where to change that in the code. For example, `25,000` will output `25k` and i dont want that to happen. Anyone knows how i can prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `lang.numericSymbols` in the defaultOptions to `null`. By default they are set to `['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E']`

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    numericSymbols: null 
  }
});
```

This is described in the documentation here: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#lang.numericSymbols